# Custom dashed line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

[image: style model dash double dot dash]

I want to create a line style in QGIS (model is attached here with),

Answer (score 7):

It is possible with the style tool. Below an example with Qgis 2.2:

[image: Example of custom dash pattern]

and the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Note that he has only one dash and two dots. therefore the pattern should be: [1.4,1][0,0.85][0,1]. without the last "dash"

Comment: @HDunn - You're definitely right. The last dash is not needed: sorry! It's lunch time.

Comment: This will work in a lot of older QGIS versions too. It's been there for a long while.

Comment: @NathanW - I rightly generalized the answer.